# How to properly use Gophish python API to avoid this Json mess?

Tags: python, json

So, I am trying to use the Gophish with my Python 3.7 project to allow users to create campaigns, profiles and all the good stuff you can normaly do in the UI. So looking at the package documentation, I tried using the code to create a new campaign or user group or anything, but I keep getting a JSON error.

Using python 3.7, with Gophish 0.7.1, tried changing names or even using direct input instead of hardcoded values, none of this solve anything, and I quite don't understand the Json at all, all I want is my python program to work

```
def newCampaign():
    groups = [Group(name='testgroup')]
    page = Page(name='Linkedin')
    template = Template(name='Linkedin')
    smtp = SMTP(name='LinkedIN')
    url = 'http://192.168.1.20'
    campaign = Campaign(name='Example Campaign', groups=groups, page=page, template=template, smtp=smtp)
    campaign = api.campaigns.post(campaign)


newCmpgnBut = Button(self, text="NEW CAMPAIGN", command=newCampaign(), bg='black', fg='white')
newCmpgnBut.pack()
```

I expect this to create a new campaign in my Gophish, instead all I get is this messy lot:

```
File "/PycharmProjects/PenTester2.0/phishing.py", line 45, in <module>
    newCmpgnBut = Button(self, text="NEW CAMPAIGN", command=newCampaign(), bg='black', fg='white')
  File "/PycharmProjects/PenTester2.0/phishing.py", line 40, in newCampaign
    campaign = api.campaigns.post(campaign)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gophish/api/campaigns.py", line 20, in post
    return super(API, self).post(campaign)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gophish/api/api.py", line 92, in post
    raise Error.parse(response.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out in the API/campaigns.py and all the other api files, there is an additional '/' in path of line 7, which causes two slashes to be added in an address to access the file. removing the slash solves the issue